# *ngIf doesn't work in an an Angular Material table when using an observable

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to use an Angular Material table with expandable rows, to show information only if the screen width is below a particular breakpoint.  I'm using an observable `isHandSetPortrait$`, that I'm subscribing to in my HTML, to determine whether the breakpoint has been reached.

The table has two columns (*Name*, and *Info*). *Name* is displayed whether `isHandsetPortrait` is true or false, and *Info* is only displayed when `isHandsetPortrait$` is `false`.  This works as expected.

In the expandable row, I have an `*ngIf` that uses the same observable `isHandsetPortrait$`, to display text when the output of `isHandsetPortrait$` is `true`.  However, this doesn't appear to be working.

## table-expandable-rows-example.html

```
<!-- *ngIf works here -->
  <div *ngIf="isHandsetPortrait$ | async">ngIf works here</div>
  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="priority" matSortDirection="desc"
           multiTemplateDataRows>


      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Info Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="info" >
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="info-cell">
          Info
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
          <div class="expanded-content" [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
            Additional text....
            <!-- *ngIf does not work here -->
            <div *ngIf="isHandsetPortrait$ | async">ngIf does not work here</div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="getDisplayedColumns(isHandsetPortrait$ | async)"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: getDisplayedColumns(isHandsetPortrait$ | async);"
          class="example-element-row" [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
          (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

### table-expandable-rows-example.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';
import { from, Observable, of, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, delay, map, share } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

/**
 * @title Table with expandable rows
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-expandable-rows-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-expandable-rows-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-expandable-rows-example.html',
animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0' })),
      state('expanded', style({ height: '*' })),
      transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)'))
    ]),
  ]
})
export class TableExpandableRowsExample {

    public isHandsetPortrait$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait)
    .pipe(
      map(orientationState => orientationState.matches),
      share()
    );

  private chatRequests = [
    {
      name: 'John Wayne'
    },
    {
      name: 'Oscar Wilde'
    },
    {
      name: 'Eric Cantona'
    }
  ];

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.chatRequests);

  displayedColumns: { def: string, isMobile: boolean }[] = [
    {
      def: 'name',
      isMobile: true
    },
    {
      def: 'info',
      isMobile: false
    }
  ];

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) { }


  public getDisplayedColumns(isHandsetPortrait: boolean) {
    return this.displayedColumns
      .filter(cd => !isHandsetPortrait || cd.isMobile)
      .map(cd => cd.def);
  }

}
```

I've put together a [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ml4vym?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html) that should highlight the issue I'm having.

The `*ngIf` works outside of the table (Line 2 of the `html` template), but does not work inside the table (Line 28 of the `html` template).  How can I make the second `*ngIf` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use **shareReplay** to make it works, using **share** nothing will happen for the second subscriber

```
public isHandsetPortrait$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait)
.pipe(
  map(orientationState => orientationState.matches),
  shareReplay(1) // here
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ml4vym-71mba5

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for this!  I had fundamentally misunderstood how `share()` worked; changing my code to your solution fixed it for me.  Thanks again!